# Can we train google vision OCR to read printed complex mathematical expressions?

Tags: math, ocr, mathematical-expressions, google-vision

Google Vision OCR API is unable to read mathematical expressions, can we train it to  read the complex mathematical expressions? If yes, please let us know the procedure. If not, can you please suggest some other OCRs which can serve the purpose? We need them as API, which we can integrate with our app.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Mathematical expressions could mean anything from arithmetic to differential and integral equations.   If you could train a NN to read them, what would you do next?  That's too broad.  I'd narrow your requirements.

Comment: Hi, please take a look at https://mathpix.com/api.html